# MySQL Using IN() SubQuery Creates Much Longer Execution Time

Tags: mysql

What is the difference between the following?  The first query takes 0.00 to execute, the second takes 0.00 to execute, the third takes 0.71 to execute.  For some reason when I put the two queries together in example 3 it takes much longer to execute.  Table traffic has an index on shortcode and ip, table redirect has an index on campaign and pubid.

Is there another type of index that could speed this scenario up?

Query 1: (0.00 Execution)

```
SELECT * FROM traffic 
    WHERE shortcode IN ('CODE1')
    GROUP BY ip
```

Query 2: (0.00 Execution)

```
SELECT shortcode FROM redirect WHERE campaign = '385' AND pubid = '35'
```

Query 3: (0.71 Execution)

```
SELECT * FROM traffic 
    WHERE shortcode IN 
        (SELECT shortcode FROM redirect WHERE campaign = '385' AND pubid = '35') 
    GROUP BY ip
```

Comment: before answering, can you provide the execution plan of the three queries? usually, it's the starting point to detect any performance issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In older versions of MySQL, the `IN ( SELECT ... )` construct was very poorly optimized.  For every row in `traffic` it would re-execute the subquery.  What version of MySQL are you using?  The simple and efficient solution was to turn it into a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT  t.*
    FROM  traffic AS t
    JOIN  redirect AS r USING(shortcode)
    WHERE  campaign = '385'
      AND  pubid = '35'
    GROUP BY  ip
```

You also need `INDEX(campaign, pubid, shortcode)` .

There is a "bug" in the either query -- You are asking for all columns, but grouping by only `ip`.  If the rest of the columns are not really dependent on `ip`.

Comment: This answer is incredible!  It took a much longer (similar) query from 4.07 to 0.00 execution time.